# Valor inesperado comparando cadenas en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una comparación de cadenas y obtengo un resultado inesperado. Así:

```
 var es = "";
         do {
             es = varsesionserver("estado");
             sleep(1000);
          } while (es == "");
              
          console.log("El valor devuelto de 'es': " + es);
          console.log("El valor de 'es' convertido en minúsculas: " + 
            es.toLowerCase());
              var g;
              g = (es.toLowerCase() == "escrinf");
console.log("El resultado de la comparación es: " + g);
```

La salida en console es la siguiente:

```
El valor devuelto de 'es': escrInf
El valor de 'es' convertido en minúsculas: escrinf
El resultado de la comparación es: false
```

El resultado que esperaba en la tercera línea de log es "El resultado de la comparación es: *true*". Sin embargo es *false*. La comparación es entre los valores 'escrinf' y 'escrinf'. El primero resultado de la conversión en minúsculas de la variable **es**, y el segundo es una cadena escrita directamente, un literal.
*Varsesionserver* es una función que hace una llamada Ajax y finalmente obtiene el valor de la variable de sesión *estado*. Como se ve en la salida del log el valor devuelto es 'escrInf'. En un principio creo que puede descartarse que esa sea la causa del problema. Es una cadena.

Comment: es false por que niegas la expresión :/

Comment: como dice @Christian debes ponerlo asi `if (es.toString().toLowerCase() == "escrinf") {}` pero con colocar `if (es.toLowerCase() == "escrinf") {}` debería funcionarte

Comment: Hola! Realmente la expresión debe ser negada en mi código para que arroje un resultado correcto. Ahora he modificado la pregunta para que no genere ninguna confusión.

Comment: Es decir... dices que el valor unas lineas antes es `escrinf` pero unas lineas despues cuando comparas con esa variable ya no es `escrinf`? Se me ocurren 2 posibilidades, que estes haciendo console.log de la variable y te muestre `escrinf` en consola, pero realmente la variable no sea un string, puede ser cualquier cosa que en consola muestre ese valor.... O si realmente si es un string con ese valor, puede ser posible que en alguna de las lineas siguientes estés cambiando el valor de esa variable sin querer. Podrías agregar las lineas intermedias donde dices que si tenia valor y luego no?

Comment: Hola! He vuelto a reformular la pregunta incluyendo el código y el resultado con console.log. Así espero que se entienda mejor el problema. Gracias!

Comment: Comprueba que lo que te devuelve `varsesionserver("estado")` no tiene espacios delante o detras. En mis pruebas, forzando esa función, me da true. Míralo [aquí mismo](https://jsfiddle.net/31yrb9zm/)

Comment: Efectivamente, es ese el problema. He leído la longitud del valor devuelto y es 9, cuando los caracteres alfabéticos de "escrInf" son 7.  Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @masterguru, me ha resultado muy útil tu respuesta. ¿Cómo puedo valorarla en el foro si está como comentario y no en respuestas?

Comment: No puedes :-)  Tan solo dale al icono de ^ que hay al lado de mi comentario (si te deja, quizas no tienes aun suficiente reputacion) para que sea mejor valorado entre los comentarios, pero nada más.  Supongo que alguien leerá mi comentario y te desarrollará una respuesta mas completa usando [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim?retiredLocale=ca) y la deberás marcar como aceptada para que la pregunta no quede pendiente para siempre. (yo no lo voy a hacer, no tengo tiempo ahora)

Comment: De acuerdo. Hecho. La función trim() la conozco. No la empleo justo ahí porque que se devuelvan dos caracteres de espacio es absolutamente sorpresivo. De hecho uso esa función en otros puntos y nunca me ha devuelto con espacios los valores. Realmente lo que tengo que inspeccionar es dónde se generan esos caracteres de espacio más que eliminar con trim(). Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente se deba a que la variable **es** la estás usando fuera del rango en el que la declaraste, bajo esta premisa supongo que no te ha marcado error porque **no estás usando la ultima versión de ECMAScript**

Comment: Hola! No, uso JavaScript estándar. Sobre la posibilidad que comentas la variable "es" la declaro así:   var es = "(r)".  Posteriormente se comprueba si es distinta a "(r)" y se sale de una iteración correctamente con el valor de "es" igual a "escrInf". Pero esta última cadena contenida en "es" es la que al compararla con la cadena "escrInf" (y también modificada con toString y ToLowerCase) nunca da true (sin usar el operador de negación), o false (usando el operador de negación).

Comment: Hola! He vuelto a reformular la pregunta incluyendo el código y el resultado con console.log. Así espero que se entienda mejor el problema. Gracias! –

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).